# OpenLayers 3 FeatureOverlay override feature style

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have a web map written using OpenLayers 3.0, which I am trying to upgrade to OpenLayers 3.6.
The FeatureOverlay seems to behave completely differently.
I have KML layers with styles defined for each feature, and I want to use a FeatureOverlay with a style override to highlight features as the mouse moves over them. 
In OL3.0 this worked fine, but in OL3.6, the feature style always takes preference over the FeatureOverlay style, so the hover highlight does not show up. This functionality changes seems to defeat the point of having the FeatureOverlay class - I may as well just temporarily change the feature style.

Is there a way to override the feature style when adding features to a FeatureOverlay?

Define my KML layer:

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: layerUrl,
        format: new ol.format.KML({
            extractStyles: true
        })
    })
});
```

Define my FeatureOverlay:

```
var hoverOverlay = new ol.FeatureOverlay({
    map: map,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: "orange",
            width: 3
        })
    })
});
```

Add feature to hoverOverlay in pointermove event:

```
hoverOverlay.addFeature(feature);
```

If I set extractStyles: false in the ol.format.KML constructor, the highlight works, but I lose my original KML styles.
I would like FeatureOverlay to work as it did in OL3.0. Is this possible?
Or should I just forget about the FeatureOverlay and temporarily change the style of a feature to highlight it?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: There's no `ol.FeatureOverlay` anymore in v3.7 and higher, so you could prepare your code to the latest version.

Comment: So the preferred approach now is to modify individual feature styes for hover/select events? That is what I am doing to workaround this issue.
I am not used to working with such a fast-changing/unstable API!

Comment: Do you still need help? And what version for?

Comment: I have worked around the problem for now, by changing the feature styles individually, but this feels like a cludge. i am sticking with 3.6 for the moment - I don't want to keep up with the latest version if the API is continually changing.

Comment: I see, but the changes are not so huge.